# Настройка Nginx Django ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

Нужна помощь с настройкой сервера Nginx

Проблема в том, что сервер прекрасно работает на 80 порту
http://localhost/
http://127.0.0.1/
http://example.ru
Все открывается

Не работает
https://localhost/
https://127.0.0.1/
https://example.ru
Выдает ошибку
Не удается получить доступ к сайтуСайт localhost неожиданно разорвал соединение.
Попробуйте сделать следующее:
Проверьте подключение к Интернету.
Проверьте настройки прокси-сервера и брандмауэра.
Выполните диагностику сети в Windows
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

При обращение по
https://127.0.0.1:8000/
Этот сайт не может обеспечить безопасное соединениеСайт 127.0.0.1 отправил недействительный ответ.
Выполните диагностику сети в Windows.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Первоначальную настройку Nginx выполнял по инструкции
https://help.reg.ru/support/ssl-sertifikaty/3-etap-ustanovka-ssl-sertifikata/kak-nastroit-ssl-sertifikat-na-nginx

nginx.conf

```
events {}
http {
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.ru localhost;

    # SSL-сертификаты
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/example.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/ca.crt;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example_app:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
 }}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  imggen_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  example_app:
    container_name: example_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: >
      sh -c "
        python3.9 backend/example_app/manage.py check &&
        python3.9 backend/example_app/manage.py makemigrations &&
        python3.9 backend/example_app/manage.py migrate &&
        python3.9 backend/example_app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    networks:
      - imggen_network

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro 
    depends_on:
      - example_app
    networks:
      - imggen_network
```

Возможно я не там смотрю, возможно проблема в настройки джанго?

Comment: Вы слушаете порт 80 на IPv4 и порт 443 на IPv6, а вот порт 443 на IPv4 вы не слушаете, читайте документацию к listen

Comment: И порт 8000 пробрасывать не надо, так как тогда в наличии nginx нет никакого смысла

Comment: И команду runserver тоже использовать не надо, она предназначена только для разработки и пускать её в продакшен категорически нельзя

Comment: Спасибо @andreymal, добавил listen 443 ssl; - локальное подключение есть, теперь ошибка err_connection_timed_out, но есть подозрение, что тут вопросы к моему роутеру. Проверял порты на https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, 443 закрыт.
По порт 8000, я правильно понимаю, что нужно использовать expose вместо ports?
По runserver  не совсем понимаю механику, nginx сам запустит приложение?

Comment: На всякий случай проверил docker ps
0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   nginx